# ASMX Web Service

Tags: web-services, asmx

I am just working on .NET for the past six month.I am using VS 2005.I have been assigned 
a task to test a Web service.I have created a  **Web service project**  in VS 2005 IDE and a simple method that returns an ArrayList of employee type.I have the employee table in SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition.

I need to perform the following tasks :

- For testing purpose ,i need to deploy my web service  on other server

     (   ***What are the steps do i need to follow in order to host my service to other server ,i mean do i need to copy dll,config file,WSDL or something else***   )
- **Any  trusted**   Provider like google or microsoft allow us to host(deploy) our service for testing purpose
- If i suppose to deploy my web service ,i also need to deploy my Sql Server 2005 Database,because the database keeps the employee table.Do i need to copy .mdf and .ldf files to the hosting server ?
- As I am completely unaware of the free hosting providers, steps to follow to host my web service  and Database ,I am in need of you help to aid me to make my work as successful one

Advanced thanks to all seniors and helping hands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Visual Studio provides a PUBLISH command which will send all the needed files to a location of your choosing.

2) Only if you pay for such a service--but it won't be GOOGLE or MICROSOSFT.

3) Depends on where you're deploying to. But ultimately, it will be either restoring a backup of the DB or you'll need to script your DB out to a file and then run the resulting SQL on your server

4) I don't think you'll find many 'free' servers out there for this purpose. That said, it should not be that hard to repurpose a desktop workstation running XP Professional for testing the service.

Comment: @John - no, you're right. It's the Publish command.  I THINK deploy, but it's publish.